# Comparing two dictionaries and returning new dictionaries

Tags: python

Purpose: comparing two dictionaries and Returning third dictionary with key of `COUNTRIES` and value of `Country_gdps` if and when `country_gdps` key matches `COUNTRIES` value, else delete all the key value pair from `country_gdps`.

Given dictionaries snippet,the list is long with many countries, just added this as an example

```
country_gdps : {"Arab World": 2504702625568, "Caribbean small states": 66707362091,"Italy": 1858913163927, "Jamaica": 14056908749} 

COUNTRIES ={'ad': 'Andorra', 'ae': 'United Arab Emirates', 'af','it': 'Italy','jp': 'Japan'}
```

The function I tried to define, the function only works for last key -value pair

```
def compare(dict1,dict2):
    for key1,value1 in dict1.items():
    for key2 ,value2 in dict2.items():
    if key1 == dict2[key2]:
    key1 = key2
    dict3 = {key1: value1}
    return dict3 

print(compare(country_gdps,COUNTRIES))
```

I want a new dictionary whose content looks like this result= {''it':1858913163927} when key of dict1 matches value of dict2 and should not contain non matching key value pairs of dict1. such as {"Arab World": 2504702625568, "Caribbean small states": 66707362091} should not be there in new dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to fix this code"? What is wrong about it? Please describe the output that you expect and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match key of country_gdps with values of COUNTRY here is the code:

```
   country_gdps ={"Arab World": 2504702625568, "Caribbean small states": 66707362091,"Italy": 1858913163927, "Jamaica": 14056908749} 

COUNTRIES ={'ad': 'Andorra', 'ae': 'United Arab Emirates','it': 'Italy','jp': 'Japan'}


dict1={}
for i in country_gdps:
    for j in COUNTRIES :
        if i == COUNTRIES[j]:
            dict1[j]=country_gdps[i]

print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'it': 1858913163927}
```

Is this is what you want or something else was required please let me know

Comment: I have edit the code to match your requirements.If my answer is your solution make sure to mark it as your answer

Answer (score 0):

Rectify the mistake in your COUNTRIES dictionary.

```
country_gdps = {"Arab World": 2504702625568, "Caribbean small states": 66707362091,"Italy": 1858913163927, "Jamaica": 14056908749} 
COUNTRIES ={'ad': 'Andorra', 'ae': 'United Arab Emirates','it': 'Italy','jp': 'Japan'}

def compare(d1,d2,d):
    for i in d1.values():
        for j in d2.keys():
            if i == j:
                d[i] = j
                return d
    else:
        country_gdps = {}
        return country_gdps
print(compare(COUNTRIES,country_gdps,{}))
```

Output will be

```
{'Italy': 'Italy'}
```

Any other doubts are welcome.